# Drupal full screen image within page

Tags: html, css, drupal

I'm working a Drupal website and want to accomplish the following: I have a content type for adding a page with an image, anchor link and some content or form. Now the image gets displayed within the body width but I want this image to be displayed full screen. The rest of the page such as the links and content/form have to be displayed according to the body width.

How can I accomplish this cause no matter what I tried it seems I can't get that image to be displayed in full width...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a custom template for you content type, and print the image field in such a way that is not contained within any Drupal continer that already is styled to display content within it. Something like:

```
<div id="im">
  <?php echo $node->field_image[0]['path']; ?>
</div>
<div ..>

   <?php echo $body ?>

</div>
```

This isn't a working example, it's just to give you an idea. Relying only on CSS works for a certain theme but might not work for another.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you try to do. You could just accomplish a fullscreen image with CSS:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Keep in mind that in these approach aspect ratio is following browser window and not image aspect ratio. Depending on `z-index` image is in front or in background of other elements. If you like you could use `opacity` to make it transparent.